# Cassandra php driver on MacOS - Class 'Cassandra\SimpleStatement' not found

Tags: php, macos, cassandra, datastax, datastax-php-driver

Good day, everyone.

Usually I just using this [Official Docs](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md) in *nix OS

But now i'm using MacOs and this instructions just doesn't work properly.

In case of `pecl install cassandra` I got this message:

```
checking for supported DataStax C/C++ driver version... awk: can't open file /include/cassandra.h
 source line number 1
configure: error: not supported. Driver version 2.4.2+ required (found )
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/cassandra/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

My logic tell me that in that case I need make DataStax C/C++ driver by my own. In folder `php-driver\lib` I deleting `cpp-driver` and using [this instruction](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/) make new and fresh C/C++ driver without errors.

So in official doc it says:

> Note The install.sh script will also compile and statically link into the extension a submoduled version of the DataStax C/C++ driver for Apache Cassandra. To use a version of cpp driver that you already have on your system, run phpize, ./configure and make install.

But when i trying to run `./configure` from `php-drive/ext` I got almost the same error:

```
checking for supported DataStax C/C++ driver version... awk: can't open file /include/cassandra.h
 source line number 1
configure: error: not supported. Driver version 2.4.2+ required (found )
```

Even if I continue and after that error run `make install` it gives me that log:

```
/bin/sh /Users/antvirgeo/php-driver/ext/libtool --mode=install cp ./cassandra.la /Users/antvirgeo/php-driver/ext/modules
cp ./.libs/cassandra.so /Users/antvirgeo/php-driver/ext/modules/cassandra.so
cp ./.libs/cassandra.lai /Users/antvirgeo/php-driver/ext/modules/cassandra.la
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /Users/antvirgeo/php-driver/ext/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/
cp: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/#INST@24727#: Operation not permitted
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
```

> Libraries have been installed in:
>   /Users/antvirgeo/php-driver/ext/modules

Even if I adding cassandra extension with that path to php.ini I still got error `Class 'Cassandra\SimpleStatement' not found` in my project.

`php -d="extension=modules/cassandra.so" -m` showing that `cassandra` in list of PHP Modules

What am I doing wrong?

*PS: I have ubuntu OS in Parallels with this project with DataStax php driver installed with this instructions works fine.*

____upd:
After all instructions of @Fero without **ANY ERRORS**, command `/usr/local/bin/php -i | grep -A 10 "^cassandra$"` showing me this:

```
cassandra

Cassandra support => enabled
C/C++ driver version => 2.4.2
Persistent Clusters => 0
Persistent Sessions => 0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cassandra.log => cassandra.log => cassandra.log
cassandra.log_level => ERROR => ERROR
```

And still the same error - `Class 'Cassandra\SimpleStatement' not found`

______________UPDATED LAST:

Aaaaand it's working! I wrote output `phpinfo();` in my project and realize that apache using other php version and `php.ini`, where wasn't `extension=cassandra.so` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to install the DataStax C/C++ driver which is a dependency of the PHP driver. Using [these instructions](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/#os-x) followed by `make install` after the driver has been successfully built will ensure this dependency is available when building the PHP driver. Using the PHP driver [build instructions](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md#linuxos-x) you will need to make sure that GMP and PHP dev libraries are also available before running `pecl install cassandra`.

EDIT:

Since you are using El Capitan you are running into issues with the [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really/193379) and you will need to [disable](http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html) it in order to copy files into `/usr`. The better and recommended option is to install PHP using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh); however you can also use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) if preferred.

Below are the steps used to reproduce the installation of the PHP driver on a clean OSX El Capitan image with Xcode and Homebrew already installed:

```
brew install autoconf cmake libuv gmp openssl pcre homebrew/php/php55
brew link homebrew/php/php55
mkdir code
pushd code
git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
pushd php-driver
git submodule update --init --recursive
pushd lib/cpp-driver
mkdir build
pushd build
cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl ..
make -j$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
sudo make install
popd
popd
mkdir build
pushd ext
/usr/local/bin/phpize
popd
pushd build
../ext/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
make -j$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
sudo make install
popd
popd
sudo sh -c 'echo "extension=cassandra.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini'
```

You can then verify the installation using the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -i | grep -A 10 "^cassandra$"
```

NOTE: PHP v5.5 is utilized above since that is the default version that comes with El Capitan; PHP v5.6 and v7.0 can also be used instead.

Comment: Already done this... 
As I already wrote - when `pecl install cassandra` didn't work with built-in cpp-driver I use these instructions and build cpp-driver by my own - and he has successfully built.
And anyway that doesn't work. See errors in post

Comment: @ANTVirGEO I have edited the original answer to help you understand why the copy operation during `sudo make install` was failing for you and to give you a step-by-step/scripted instructions to build from source.

Comment: First of all - thank you for step-by-step instruction - this is very helpful!
Originally post updated.
I shut down SIP, and complete all steps, but still got the same error =\

Comment: I would recommend using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/); disabling SIP is definitely a security risk for your system. With Homebrew you can easily install multiple versions of PHP and then switch between those versions using [sphp](https://github.com/sgotre/sphp-osx) or [brew-php-switcher](https://github.com/philcook/brew-php-switcher).

Comment: One follow up question; are you using the `/usr/local/bin/php` that has the extension/module enabled for your PHP application that you are developing? The only way that class would not be found is if the extension/module was not found and since you used the command `/usr/local/bin/php -i | grep -A 10 "^cassandra$"` to see if the module was being loaded (and it appears to be based on your output) is the reason I am asking this question.

Comment: I installed new php in `/usr/local/php5-5.6.25-20160831-101628/bin/php`, and using `/usr/local/php5-5.6.25-20160831-101628/bin/php -i | grep -A 10 "^cassandra$"` and apache showing exactly this version of php in my project (not the one that rooted in Mac). 


Aaaaand it's working! I output `phpinfo();` in my project and realize that apache using other `php.ini`, where wasn't `extension=cassandra.so` at all.

Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install the Cassandra PHP extension on MacOS, you can do this simply by installing it via PECL, without having to do anything with turning on or off System Integrity Protection. I've written a blog post with easy step-by-step instructions. It also includes a link to installing PHP from Homebrew since they removed the Homebrew/php tap back in April of this year.

It also by passes the incorrect instructions given on the DataStax website. In short ...

Install Dependencies (I run these commands one at a time to easily view any messages):

```
$ brew install autoconf
$ brew install cmake
$ brew install automake
$ brew install libtool
$ brew install gmp
$ brew install libuv
$ brew install openssl
```

Retrieve and build the C++ driver and then create a build directory inside the cpp-driver folder:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver.git --depth=1
$ mkdir cpp-driver/build
$ cd cpp-driver/build
```

Make and build the driver with a qualified call to OpenSSL:

```
$ cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/ -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib ..
$ make
$ make install
```

Now you're good to go to install the Cassandra PHP extension libraries using PECL:

```
$ pecl install cassandra
```

Check to make sure that the Cassandra extension was added to your PHP.ini file. If not add it.

```
[cassandra]
extension="cassandra.so"
```

Restart Apache and you're off and running with Cassandra in PHP.

If you want more detail on what's happening in the above instructions, refer to my blog post here:

https://medium.com/@crmcmullen/how-to-install-the-cassandra-php-driver-on-macos-10-13-high-sierra-and-10-14-mojave-c18263831ccb