# Laravel 4.2 and Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, laravel-4.2

How can i connect cassandra with laravel 4.2 ?

I already install php-driver from datastack and I can use it outside the laravel framework.

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra Laravel Installation

```
•   Install DataStax PHP Driver for Apache Cassandra on the server
  See https://github.com/datastax/php-driver
  pecl install cassandra
  This command will add cassandra extension in our php. Check cassandra extension using phpinfo();
  Restart php after installing the extension.


  Common issue:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348265/cassandra-php-driver-on-macos-class-cassandra-simplestatement-not-found

•   Install laravel cassandra eloquent wrapper and query builder
  See https://github.com/cubettech/lacassa
  See http://cubettech.com/laravel-cassandra/

  Add config for database. \config\database.php
  Add new providers in app. \config\app.php => 'Cubettech\Lacassa\CassandraServiceProvider'
```